# Can't access MCvRect

Tags: c#

I want to translate in c# but can't access MCvRect (public struct MCvRect)

```
cvSetImageROI(img1, cvRect(10, 15, 150, 250)); // Opencv

in c#
CvInvoke.cvSetImageROI(img1, new MCvRect(...));// how to do in c#
CvInvoke.cvSetImageROI(img1, ......)// why i can't see MCvRect
```

I am using Emgu , VS2010.
 regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the new code you have posted, this should do what you want:

```
Rectangle yourRect = new Rectangle(20,20,200,200);
img_scene_.ROI  = yourRect;
Image<Bgr,Byte> myimage = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(yourRect.Width, yourRect.Height);
img_scene.Copy(myimage, null);
img_scene.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;
```

Comment: thanx a lot, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ROI property of Image class

```
img.ROI = new Rectangle(...);
....
....
img.ROI = Rectangle.Empty; //in case you need to clear your ROI
```

Comment: I see nothing by running this code. Definately there is some mistake                                                img_scene_.ROI = new Rectangle(20, 20, 200, 200);
Image<Bgr,Byte> myimage =  img_scene_.Clone();
ImageViewer.Show(myimage);